# Official Pi Display supported Android things

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, android-things

I got a new project and planned to use a raspberry pi 3, Android Things and a touchscreen.
First I bought a 3.5 inch SPI touchscreen, but couldn't get it to work on Android Things so I'm looking for alternatives (as 3.5 inch proofed to be a bit to small anyways).

I couldn't find reliable sources on using touchscreens in Android Things, so I figured I'd asked here if anyone got experience in this?

My best candidate so far is the official display:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/ but if someone knew of a better one, ideally trans-reflective for outdoor use, that would be highly appreciated ;)

Comment: Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639973/anyone-have-pointers-on-how-to-access-a-touchscreen-on-raspberry-pi-with-android I decided to give it a shot and order the official raspberry pi display. It would have been nice to find a transreflective display, but it seems that there are only the Pixel Qi displays and they are way too expensive for my budget / the kind of project. -- I'll keep you posted ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After receiving my Official Raspberry Pi Display I can confir it works flawlessly with android things, also the touch-interface. There are two things to consider:

- The Demo-App of android things doesn't support touch. So quickly build your own app with some sliders and stuff like that to test it out.
- Expect some delay on the display / touch (for example when you're dragging a slider), as the hardware of the rPI 3 is quite weak ;)

Regards
Christian